# Making a keyevent in a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, keylistener

I'm trying to make a key make something happen in a JFrame. Right now I'm just trying to disable a button when you press the left key, but nothing is happening. I thought I have everything right, but it does nothing.

EDIT: I noticed that when I don't click start first, it works. But after you press start, it won't respond.

Here's my code so far:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;



public class MyFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener, KeyListener
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JPanel p1;
private JButton b1, b2;
private JLabel lb1;
private int a;
private Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20);


public MyFrame()
{
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    setSize(700,600);
    setVisible(true);
    setResizable(false);
    addKeyListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);

    p1 = new JPanel(); add(p1);
    p1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    p1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(650,500));
    p1.setFocusable(true);
    b1 = new JButton("Start"); add(b1);
    b1.addActionListener(this);
    b2 = new JButton("Test"); add(b2);
    b2.setFocusable(true);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{
    Graphics g = p1.getGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(30, 210, 10, 70);
    g.fillRect(620, 210, 10, 70);
    for(int i=0; i<7; i++)
    {
        g.fillRect(325, a, 10, 70);
        a += 90;
    }
    g.setFont(font);
    g.drawString("Player 1: ", 120, 20);
    g.drawString("Player 2: ", 450, 20);
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
{
    int d = e.getKeyCode();
    if(d==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
    {
        b2.setEnabled(false);
    }
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) 
{


}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) 
{


}

}
```

And here's my Main.java file:

```
public class Main { 
public static void main(String[] arg)
{
    MyFrame mf = new MyFrame();
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to tell the JFrame that it should be listening for keys with this line of code:`addKeyListener(this);`

Comment: Worked for me now, but won't respond after you click start. What's happening?

Comment: That is a focus problem, when you click the start button, you are changing the panel and thus changing the focus of the application, add this line to the end of the`actionPerformed` method so that the`frame` regain the focus:`requestFocus();`

Answer (score 3):

`KeyListener` has a lot of problems, with regards to focus (among other things). With Swing, it is preferred to use [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), which gives us more control over the focus options. There are different `InputMap`s for `WHEN_FOCUSED`, `WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT`, `WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW`. Their names are almost self documenting. So if we were to do

```
JPanel panel = (JPanel)frame.getContentPane();
InputMap imap = panel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
```

then we are getting the `InputMap` for when the frame is focused. We would then bind a `KeyStroke` with an [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) to that `InputMap` and the component's `ActionMap`. For example

```
JPanel panel = (JPanel)frame.getContentPane();
InputMap imap = panel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
imap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("LEFT"), "leftAction");
ActionMap amap = panel.getActionMap();
Action leftAction = new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        doSomethingWhenLeftIsPressed();
    }
};
amap.put("leftAction", leftAction);
```

---

**Resources**

- [How to use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html)
- [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)