# Dynamic FlowLayout

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, keylistener

I'm trying to make a program that take inputs from user and when user presses enter, arranges the properties of the buttons in my FlowLayout panel. But apparently my code is not working. There is no error though.

```
package hm2v;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class LayoutM extends JFrame {

static String[] alc = {"LEFT", "RIGHT"};

static JLabel align = new JLabel("Aligment ");
static JLabel hgap = new JLabel("HGap ");
static JLabel vgap = new JLabel("VGap ");

final static JComboBox aligncom = new JComboBox(alc);
final static JTextField hgaptext = new JTextField(10);
final static JTextField vgaptext = new JTextField(10);

final static FlowLayout exL = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 3, 4);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    new LayoutM();

    LayoutM frame = new LayoutM();
    frame.setTitle("Dynamic FlowLayout");
    frame.setSize(400, 325);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

public LayoutM() {

    Container contain = getContentPane();
    contain.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    final FlowLayout exL = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 3, 4);

    final JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.setLayout(exL);
    panel1.setBorder(new TitledBorder("A Container of FlowLayout"));
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        panel1.add(new JButton("Component " + i));
    }

    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    panel2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panel2.setBorder(new TitledBorder("FlowLayout Properties"));

    JPanel p3 = new JPanel();
    p3.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1, 0, 5));

    JPanel p4 = new JPanel();
    p4.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1, 0, 5));

    p3.add(align);
    p3.add(hgap);
    p3.add(vgap);

    p4.add(aligncom);
    p4.add(hgaptext);
    p4.add(vgaptext);

    panel2.add(p3, BorderLayout.WEST);
    panel2.add(p4);

    contain.add(panel1);
    contain.add(panel2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                System.out.println("Enter pressed");

                aligncom.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                        int x = aligncom.getSelectedIndex();
                        switch (x) {
                            case 0: {
                                exL.setAlignment(FlowLayout.LEFT);
                            }
                            case 1: {
                                exL.setAlignment(FlowLayout.RIGHT);
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                    }

                });

                hgaptext.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        String y = hgaptext.getText();
                        int z = Integer.parseInt(y);

                        exL.setHgap(z);

                    }
                });

                vgaptext.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        String v = vgaptext.getText();
                        int g = Integer.parseInt(v);

                        exL.setHgap(g);

                    }
                });

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

    });

}
}
```

When I enter the inputs and press enter, nothing changes and It doesn't write "Enter pressed". Where am I doing a mistake ? Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### First Problem

You are trying to add a KeyListener to the frame. I don't see why you would need this. As I understand the question, when the user hits enter after typing, something should happen.

You can accomplish this just by adding an `ActionListener` to the text field. As long as the field still has focus, this will work. And this is how you want it (for the field to have focus). So get rid of the `KeyListener`

### Second Problem

Even if the KeyListener *did* work, you aren't even doing anything but adding a new listener to the component. So every time the key is pressed, all that's happening is another listener is added to the component... nothing else.

### Third Problem

You need to `revalidate` and `repaint` the `panel1` after any of the layout changes have been made

```
 panel1.revalidate();
 panel1.repaint();
```

### In Conclusion

1. Get completely rid of the `KeyListener` (Delete it, and leave everything else the same - leaving the code inside the keypressed method)
2. Revalidate and repaint the `panel1` in both the `ActionListeners` and the `ItemListener`.

This is all you need to get it to work

Oh and you are missing a `break` in the `0` case

```
case 0: {
   exL.setAlignment(FlowLayout.LEFT);
   break;
}
```

---

### UPDATE

> User selects "Left" or "Right", types HGap and VGap, only after user presses enter, they change.

You basically have to take out all the listeners we were just working on, and add a key binding to the content pane. [You can see this post and use the same code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26626763/2587435). Just change the "LEFT" to "ENTER". And the doSomethingWhenLeftIsPressed() method you should just get the values from the combo box and fields and set the layout, all in one

I'll post code here

```
JPanel panel = (JPanel)frame.getContentPane();
InputMap imap = panel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
imap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ENTER"), "layoutAction");
ActionMap amap = panel.getActionMap();
Action leftAction = new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        doSomethingWhenEnterIsPressed();
    }
};
amap.put("layoutAction", leftAction);

...
private void doSomethingWhenEnterIsPressed() {
    // get values from field and combo and set the layout like before
}
```

Comment: I also have a combobox. When user chooses Left or Right and types HGap and VGap; after pressing enter button, the components should change.

Comment: It's working perfect thanks but the problem is now I can only arrange left or right one time. For example, I selected left, They went left. Then I tried Right, nothing changed.

Comment: You are missing a `break` in the `case 0`

Comment: Oh yeah my bad... The last problem is It shouldn't change the alignment after user selects left or right. User selects "Left" or "Right", types HGap and VGap, only after user presses enter, they change.

Comment: That's not very intuitive for the user. If this is what you want, then why have any listeners _at all_ for the combo and text fields. I don't get it

Comment: Does that take long time to accomplish ? And BTW thank you I checked your answer.

Comment: No, not long. You basically have to take out all the listeners we were just working on, and add a key binding to the content pane. You can see [this post and use the same code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26626763/2587435). Just change the `"LEFT"` to `"ENTER"`. And the `doSomethingWhenLeftIsPressed()` method you should just get the values from the combo box and fields and set the layout, all in one

Answer (score 0):

try the function `revalidate` after new-ordering.

Comment: After setting alignment of my FlowLayout, I write panel1.revalidate(); Is that right ? Because It's not working.